# Correct way to do a jQuery hover dropdown menu (without glitchyness)

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, menu

What is your bulletproof dropdown menu code in jQuery?

EDIT: I wanted to share my final solution based on the answers below, i find this is the best dropdown solution i have found so far.  It rely's on http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html but as links don't make good answers, i will leave that code inline here as well incase it disappears in the future.

```
/*!
 * hoverIntent r7 // 2013.03.11 // jQuery 1.9.1+
 * http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html
 *
 * You may use hoverIntent under the terms of the MIT license.
 * Copyright 2007, 2013 Brian Cherne
 */
(function(e){e.fn.hoverIntent=function(t,n,r){var i={interval:100,sensitivity:7,timeout:0};if(typeof t==="object"){i=e.extend(i,t)}else if(e.isFunction(n)){i=e.extend(i,{over:t,out:n,selector:r})}else{i=e.extend(i,{over:t,out:t,selector:n})}var s,o,u,a;var f=function(e){s=e.pageX;o=e.pageY};var l=function(t,n){n.hoverIntent_t=clearTimeout(n.hoverIntent_t);if(Math.abs(u-s)+Math.abs(a-o)<i.sensitivity){e(n).off("mousemove.hoverIntent",f);n.hoverIntent_s=1;return i.over.apply(n,[t])}else{u=s;a=o;n.hoverIntent_t=setTimeout(function(){l(t,n)},i.interval)}};var c=function(e,t){t.hoverIntent_t=clearTimeout(t.hoverIntent_t);t.hoverIntent_s=0;return i.out.apply(t,[e])};var h=function(t){var n=jQuery.extend({},t);var r=this;if(r.hoverIntent_t){r.hoverIntent_t=clearTimeout(r.hoverIntent_t)}if(t.type=="mouseenter"){u=n.pageX;a=n.pageY;e(r).on("mousemove.hoverIntent",f);if(r.hoverIntent_s!=1){r.hoverIntent_t=setTimeout(function(){l(n,r)},i.interval)}}else{e(r).off("mousemove.hoverIntent",f);if(r.hoverIntent_s==1){r.hoverIntent_t=setTimeout(function(){c(n,r)},i.timeout)}}};return this.on({"mouseenter.hoverIntent":h,"mouseleave.hoverIntent":h},i.selector)}})(jQuery)


$('.menu > li.menu-item').hoverIntent(
  function () {
    $(this).addClass('active');
    $(this).find('.sub-menu').slideDown('medium');
  }, 
  function () {
    $(this).removeClass('active');
    $(this).find('.sub-menu').slideUp('medium', function(){
      $(this).stop(true,true);
    });
  }
);
```

Comment: For future reference, a question would be less confusing to the reader if you describe the problem first before mentioning suggested solutions or linking to code samples.

Comment: This was what I made so customers could see a sample of there Font Face for there project files.  http://jsfiddle.net/cornelas/8gNt9/1/ I dont have a fluid slideDown only because it would close then open then close, and just never fixed it cause the dropdown worked to the effect that the project required.

Comment: @Zhihao, thanks i have updated the question to have the question first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you move mouse in and out new animation gets appended each time, its not constant loop, it will be stopped when all animations will be finished.
All you need is to add stop(true,true) to stop all previous animations.
Both true arguments mean clear animations queued to this element, and go to end of the animation.

Good place for it would be after slideUp animation finished

```
$('ul.file_menu').slideUp('medium', function(){
    $(this).stop(true,true);
    });
```

See another [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/paulitto/4jxph/1713/)

Comment: Thanks!, i was missing the two arguments in my stop! But i do feel like this solution is still glitchy.  If the user quickly moves their mouse past the menu in an upward motion it pops open and closes rapidly, which serves no purpose and just looks bad.  Furthermore, if the user drags the mouse down too quickly past the menu from above, they menu does a weird flickering thing, or closes before the user has exited the menu area. http://www.waspdigital.com/glitchy-dropdown2.mov therefor, i wouldn't say this is a bulletproof solution.

Comment: ok, you are right, but there is better place where to put stop(true,true). I updated the answer and [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/paulitto/4jxph/1713/). Try to play with this one

Comment: That link is the same link as the one in your answer above.

Comment: Oh, ok, well with this code i still get the issue with the menu closes for a quick user even if their mouse hasn't exited the dropdown area. see: http://waspdigital.com/glitchy-dropdown3.mov

Comment: indeed ) what else you can do - is to add global flag that would block popup slideup while slidedown is not finished yet, have a look at one more [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/paulitto/4jxph/1715/)

Comment: That one gets stuck open easily. swipe your mouse past it from underneath in an upward direction. It stays open, and doesn't close. Which is actually one of the problems i was having with my original code when i tried to make a global flag like that.

Answer (score 1):

Hey why dont you use hoverIntent jquery plugin. It's great. It waits for user's mouse to be stationary before triggering animation.

http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html

I personally love this plugin...

Comment: Thanks, i would make your answer as correct as well, if i could mark both.